# Html.RenderParial, how to pass and use the model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomePartial", Model); %>
```

My Model has a property UserID

In my partial I try this:

<%= Model.UserID %>

but I get this error:

CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserID' and no extension method 'UserID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blankman,

Make sure your partial ascx file defines the model as per the main view i.e:

```
<%@  Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Your.Model>" %>
```

**[edit]** - as Stefanvds mentions below, if you only need the id portion from the model, then define your partial as:

```
<%@  Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int>" %>
```

that would be the definitive i reckon :)

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that at the top of your partial view you have `Inherits` attribute of your `Control` tag set to the type of the model you're passing in:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyNamespace.MyStronglyTypedModel>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DB.Models.TheModelYouWantToSend>" %>
```

your partial should start with this.

also, if you want to send the whole model, you dont need to specify it.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomePartial"); %>
```

or if you would only like to send the ID.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomePartial", Model.UserID); %>
```

which would make the header

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int>" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The model type on your Partial View and the model you pass in to Html.RenderPartial method should match.